# Design pattern for similar request response

Tags: design-patterns, request, response

i need to design a service that consumes a request and produces a response. In terms of structure, I want the response to essentially echo the request AND also include a status.

e.g.

Request:

```
class Request {
String x;
String y;
}

class Response {
String x;
Status x_s;
String y;
Status y_s;
}
```

Is anyone aware of any patterns that describe this? One solution could be to use the same object to represent the request and response, in addiiotn with an object that encapsulates the value and status e.g.

```
class Attr {
 Status status;
 String value;
}

class RequestResponse {
Attr x;
Attr y;
}
```

- This feels a bit clumsy though. E.g. the RequestResponse.attr.status would only be applicable to a response.
- Note, in terms of the impl / usage fo this, with respect to the structure of the request / response is the same, the content will actually differ. I am attempting to implement a language translation service.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not

```
public class Response {
    private Request request; // Has-a relationship
    private Status x_s;
    private Status y_s;
}
```

In addition to any design merits, this also has the added benefit that you "reuse" the memory already allocated for the request.  It also lets you make use of functionality defined in the Request class when generating/handling the response, as in Request.getRequestType() or similar.

Another solution is to have Response inherit from request (is-a relationship), but the compositional approach is usually better

Comment: Thanks. Does ur model provide a clean way for the client to determine what status field relates to which request field. That is, how does "response.request.x_value" relate to "response.x_status". By clean, I guess I mean in a type safe way, that does not use reflection.

Comment: Why it will have same value?

Comment: it wont have the same value. The properties will be related though. One will contain a value, the other the status of the value.

Comment: You can give Status a reference into the Request field that it applies to.  This has its drawbacks; you're increasing coupling, which should generally be avoided.  Any way you slice it there's going to be compromises with the design you've chosen, and without knowing more about what you're doing I can't really give advice as to which compromise is better.  You may want to consider revisiting the design from a higher level.